# If Facebook Feed dialog is deprecated, how are you to share posts on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been working on a Facebook app for some time, and we are having trouble getting the app approved. I feel like Facebook's app approval process is a constantly moving target and their explanations are provide the least amount of detail possible, leaving the door open for further rejections.

We are using a Facebook app to provide sharing functionality for products that are behind a paywall. All of our share buttons are custom, so they fit in our designs (we don't want to use the out of the box buttons). We first built the app attempting to use the recommended share dialog with open graph actions and stories. The problem here is that you can only use the share dialog with a shared link. Facebook reads any open graph tags on the page to provide sharing information, but because there are many different "products" on a given page, we can't use open graph tags. Because of our environment, we couldn't use the actions or stories. Furthermore, we'd like to customize that share information, so using share dialog is not an option.

Unfortunately, we had left our open graph stories and actions in our app when we first attempted approval. In our first denial, Facebook told us that we had implemented our open graph actions and stories incorrectly. We were not using the share dialog, but the 'feed' method, which is deprecated in 2.0 but still works. Thinking that Facebook looked at our app and noticed we were not using those actions correctly, we figured if we removed those stories and actions from the app, Facebook would see our share method worked and approve us. Wrong.

We had built the share using the publish_actions permission, along with FB.login() and FB.ui(). Facebook denied us because our app did not need publish_actions. They recommended we use the share dialog which did not need login or permissions.

We removed the publish_actions permission and FB.login(). When we tested this, you could still login to Facebook and perform the share WITHOUT fb.login(). So we thought it was good to go. It was not; Facebook told us we needed to implement login(), even thought the docs say you *don't* need it.

Now we have reimplemented login() and are going to try to get it approved again, but I have a feeling it's going to get rejected due to the 'feed' method being deprecated.

So my questions are: 
A) If you have a website providing a paid service, how do you allow your users to post to their feeds, using the newer share method, with data you'd like? Eg: "I just completed the Get Moving III workout at teamexos.com!" The post would contain no pics or links. If it had to, a link to teamexos.com would be ok.

B) How do paid sites provide open graph actions and stories? Do they have public links to their products? Do those products have their own individual pages, with their own open graph tags?

Comment: I would also like to know. The website of my customers is not paid, but they don't want separate pages for the objects we want to share; they are dynamically populated via AJAX + JS and clicking on any of them yields a popup, from which you could share to various social networks.

Facebook is not working, and is rejecting the requests with 500 Internal Server Error.

Could you please elaborate on how did you implement `FB.login()` by yourself? I am stuck as well and if you could help a bit, it would be very nice of you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the feed dialog is not deprecated, at least not anymore. You do not need to get anything approved for it, and you certainly don´t need login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

But: Your example looks like an Open Graph story, you should consider taking a look at those: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph